# Smite the [technology-choice] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [technology-choice](/questions/tagged/technology-choice) should be smited, with great vengeance and furious anger.  It is just a legacy meta tag for recommendations.

There only 72 questions tagged with it right now, with a third already closed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418864/which-language-program-is-best-to-create-a-screen-audio-capture-software for example), and two-thirds needing to be closed (such as [html 5 v/s XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993210/html-5-v-s-xhtml)).

We *could* manually remove the tags, but this is a tag that shouldn't come back.

**2013-06-24 update**

Only 16 to go, and we can cross this off our list.

Comment: BURNINATION mode: Active!

Comment: So. Many. Bad. Questions.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Please stop editing the tag out of all of those questions. Most of those need other changes as well (eg. I just spotted a few where you missed typos), and a lot of the questions in that tag need to be closed or deleted. See the answer below.

Comment: @Asad I'm voting to close the 'bad' ones that I come across, and voting to delete the closed ones. I also have a [list](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/105020) of the ones that were tagged that, and we have my editing history. No worries, mate.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023202/web-site-effect-choice-of-technology) is bad enough to be deleted, for example. No delete vote.

Comment: @Asad I flagged that one as VLQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That tag really collected some winners.

Before burninating the tag, we should go through and vote to close / flag the questions so they can be closed as appropriate.

I've gone through and closed the ones that need closing.  I'm willing to wait for the delete cycle to go through before them being deleted.  From what I saw, most if not all of them could be deleted.

Comment: Whoops, just wrote out the same thing.

Comment: Excellent, I can wait for the delete cycle.  Thanks for the speedy response from everyone!

Comment: Sorry about the somewhat tangential comment, but I was wondering about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768222/iframes-vs-ajax). Since it comes down to looking at the pros/cons of choosing one of two highly specific approaches to solving a problem, it doesn't really strike me as non-constructive, or as bad as the other questions.